# Best way to merge/concatenate/join two DataFrames with duplicate columns, but the different Datetime indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with past data. The other with a prediction. I would like to merge them so that there are no duplicate columns.

My code looks like this:

```
Past = 
                      X RealData
2019-03-27 12:30:00 8.295   True
2019-03-27 13:00:00 7.707   True
2019-03-27 13:30:00 7.518   True
2019-03-27 14:00:00 7.518   True
2019-03-27 14:30:00 7.518   True
2019-03-27 15:00:00 7.455   True
2019-03-27 15:30:00 7.518   True
2019-03-27 16:00:00 20.244  True
2019-03-27 16:30:00 20.895  True
2019-03-27 17:00:00 21.630  True
2019-03-27 17:30:00 24.360  True
2019-03-27 18:00:00 24.591  True
2019-03-27 18:30:00 26.460  True
2019-03-27 19:00:00 14.280  True
2019-03-27 19:30:00 12.180  True
2019-03-27 20:00:00 11.550  True
2019-03-27 20:30:00 9.051   True
2019-03-27 21:00:00 8.673   True
2019-03-27 21:30:00 7.791   True

Future = 
                        X           RealData
2019-03-27 22:30:00 8.450913    False
2019-03-27 23:00:00 8.494944    False
2019-03-27 23:30:00 9.058649    False
2019-03-28 00:00:00 22.055525   False
2019-03-28 00:30:00 23.344284   False
2019-03-28 01:00:00 24.793011   False
2019-03-28 01:30:00 26.203117   False
2019-03-28 02:00:00 27.897289   False
2019-03-28 02:30:00 14.187933   False
2019-03-28 03:00:00 14.110393   False
```

At the moment, I am trying:

```
past_future = pd.concat([Future, Past], axis=1, sort=True)
```

And I am getting this:

```
                  X RealData    X   RealData
2019-03-27 12:30:00 8.295   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 13:00:00 7.707   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 13:30:00 7.518   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 14:00:00 7.518   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 14:30:00 7.518   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 15:00:00 7.455   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 15:30:00 7.518   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 16:00:00 20.244  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 16:30:00 20.895  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 17:00:00 21.630  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 17:30:00 24.360  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 18:00:00 24.591  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 18:30:00 26.460  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 19:00:00 14.280  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 19:30:00 12.180  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 20:00:00 11.550  True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 20:30:00 9.051   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 21:00:00 8.673   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 21:30:00 7.791   True    NaN NaN
2019-03-27 22:30:00 NaN NaN 8.450913    False
2019-03-27 23:00:00 NaN NaN 8.494944    False
2019-03-27 23:30:00 NaN NaN 9.058649    False
2019-03-28 00:00:00 NaN NaN 22.055525   False
2019-03-28 00:30:00 NaN NaN 23.344284   False
2019-03-28 01:00:00 NaN NaN 24.793011   False
2019-03-28 01:30:00 NaN NaN 26.203117   False
2019-03-28 02:00:00 NaN NaN 27.897289   False
2019-03-28 02:30:00 NaN NaN 14.187933   False
2019-03-28 03:00:00 NaN NaN 14.110393   False
```

My expected output is just two columns:

```
                      X         RealData
2019-03-27 12:30:00 8.295   True
2019-03-27 13:00:00 7.707   True
2019-03-27 13:30:00 7.518   True
2019-03-27 14:00:00 7.518   True
...                 ...         ...
2019-03-27 22:30:00 8.450913    False
2019-03-27 23:00:00 8.494944    False
2019-03-27 23:30:00 9.058649    False
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: `pd.concat([Future, Past]).drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 that has not worked for me, unless there is a kwarg that goes in the bracket that I am missing

Comment: you could try something like `output = pd.concat([Future.reset_index(), Past.reset_index()], axis=0)` then set the  index with `output.set_index('index', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2):

My simple advice - keep everything in the order.
Then everything is easy.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('c:/4/a1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('c:/4/a2.csv')
df2.dtypes
```

[image]

```
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2.dtypes

df1.set_index(df1.date, inplace=True)
df2.set_index(df2.date, inplace=True)


df = df1.append(df2)
df.sort_index()
df.drop_duplicates('date',keep='last', inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to formalise what ags29 wrote here [Best way to merge/concatenate/join two DataFrames with duplicate columns, but the different Datetime indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381471/best-way-to-merge-concatenate-join-two-dataframes-with-duplicate-columns-but-th#comment97487637_55381471)

```
output = pd.concat([Future.reset_index(), Past.reset_index()], axis=0)
output.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

While Wojciech Moszczyński's answer is much more thorough, this seems to do the job quite well.